# Django Cache Implementation

Tags: django, django-cache, django-caching

Well, I'm designing a web application using Django. The application allow users to select a photo from the computer system and keep populating onto the users timeline. The timeline view have a list/grid of all the photos which the user has uploaded sorted chronologically, showing 50 photos and then a pull to refresh to fetch the next 50 photos on the timeline.The implementation works for multiple users.

Now for fast user experience of the app I'm considering caching. Like most sites store the timeline of the user onto cache so that whenever the user logs in it the first place to check for information the request is served out of  the cache and if it is not available there then you go to the DB to query for the information.

Primarily in one line I'm trying to cache all the timelines for different users in cache for now.

I'm done with building of the webapp minus the cache part. So , my question is how do I cache all the timelines of different users??

Answer (score 0):

There is a big difference between public caching and the caching of private data. I feel your data is private and thus needs a different strategy. There is a nice overview of the different ways to implement testing and, more importantly, the different things you need to take into account: [The Server Side (Tom Eastman)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=nTMupredqR0&t=980). This has a part on speed and caching (16:20 onward). It explains how to use `etag` and `last_modified` headers with django.